# How can I seperate a remeshed object (Remesh modifier/Voxelization) into different cubes?

Tags: modifiers, remesh

I used the *Remesh* modifier to turn this torus into voxels (cubes). I would like to have each individual cube as a different object. Even after applying the modifier, I encountered two problems:

1. The faces are connected, therefore separating them by loose parts doesn't work.
2. The modifier does not turn the object into cubes, but rather into faces to make them appear like cubes.

Is there any way to use the modifier or something else like an array to turn my object into many different cubes?

[image: remeshed object cut open][image: faces still connected]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use this geometry nodes setup:

[image]

then you can apply all modifiers and separate by loose parts after applying.

Play around with the size of your cube by changing the scale or size values.

[image]

[image]